# USB based HSM, preferably with open source firmware and able to sign with 4096 bit RSA key in under 1 sec for under US$500

Tags: usb, hardware-security-module

I am in search of an HSM which can be plugged in via USB and which is able to sign - via OpenSC or PKCS#11 module -, using an RSA 4096 bit key created and stored on it, in under one second.

Example:

- YubiHSM 2 FIPS: fits the bill performance-wise, but is considerably more expensive and doesn't feature an open source firmware
- Nitrokey HSM 2: open source firmware, costs under US$100, but considerably slower (according to their datasheet 4100 ms for a signature as specified)